# SQL функция, преобразующая число в строку

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо разработать функцию, которая возвращала бы строку к примеру вида:

```
98 целых 5 десятых
```

если входной параметр будет число 98.5 типа `NUMBER(4,1)`.

Пробую так:

```
declare @t numeric(4,1) = 98.5
select REPLACE(@t, '.', N' целых ') + N' десятых'
```

Comment: Задача вроде бы тривиальная... Какие у вас возникли затруднения?

Comment: @MaxU, есть ли какая нибудь функция которая переобразует число на строку? конкретно для данного примера я мог бы написать запрос через case when

Comment: В Oracle это функция `to_char()` или `cast()`...

Comment: @MaxU, то есть  в параметре передается число и нам нужно возвращать число виде строки     примерно так  но then нужно править                                                      declare @t numeric(4,1) = 98.5
select case when @t=ABS(98.5) then N'98 целых 5 десятых' end

Comment: приведите больше примеров - как будет выглядеть результат для целых чисел, отрицательных, числа `0` и т.д.?

Comment: @MaxU, параметр всегда будет целое число(1, 2.6 , 4 итд) результат запроса привел выше  "2 целых 6 десятых "

Comment: @ MaxU, кажется тут нужно использовать replace если в параметре точка то слово десятых итд

Comment: вам нужно что-то вроде [этого](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0270cf/5)?

Comment: А на какой БД должно выполнятся? Судя по вашему примеру, на sql-server.

Comment: @0xdb, да на sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0270cf/5):

```
select replace(cast(n as varchar), '.', N' целых ') + N' десятых' from tab;
```